# PHP/MYSQL query help with grouping results

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a MYSQL table with 3 fields: CODE, DATE, COUNT.

CODE is the ID of the client
DATE is the date the entry was added
COUNT is the number of credits used by that client on that date

I need to be able to know how many credits each client has used on a per month basis. So I need to group the results by client and by year/month.

Basically I need an output that will look something like this :

```
CODE     YEAR     MONTH     COUNT

123      2009       07        65

123      2009       06        35

456      2009       07        0

456      2009       06        78

789      2009       07        18
```

What I have so far is this but it's not really working :

"SELECT CODE, COUNT(CODE), SUM(COUNT), YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE) FROM table"

Any help?

Comment: You should aggregate the month and year columns in one date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am over simplyfing here but would it not be

```
SELECT CODE, COUNT(CODE), SUM(COUNT), YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE) FROM tbl GROUP BY CODE, COUNT, YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE)
```

Comment: Err, yes this worked minus the group by count. Thank you very much... I knew it had something to do with group by but I couldn't figure it out!